# Amortized time cost of exponentially costed binary counter

Tags: algorithm, amortized-analysis

If a binary counter costs O(2^i) time to change the value of the i-th bit, what is the upper bound on the total cost of n increment operations?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you start the counter at zero, then

- n operations change the 1 bit (cost O(n)),
- n/2 operations change the 2 bit (cost O(n)),
- n/4 operations change the 4 bit (cost O(n)),
- ...

This means that the cost is bounded by O(n) times the number of total bits in the counter, which is O(log n) because n-bit numbers require O(log n) bits. Therefore, the total time complexity is O(n log n), so each operation has an amortized cost of O(log n).